# How can I load image(s) used in sass stylesheet in webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am using **Webpack** to bundle my modules and using **sass** for styling purpose in a react based application.

Using a seperate style-sheet I am setting the background-image of a component and loaded that style-sheet in `index.js`. All the styles in style-sheet gets applied to that component **except background image**.

Here is my sample style-sheet

```
$bg-img: url('/img/bg.jpg');

.show {
    position: relative;
    background: $black $bg-img center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

One way to solve that problem would be explicitly require the image and then create inline style for react components.

```
img1 = document.createElement("img");
img1.src = require("./image.png");
```

But I want to **load all the images from my image folder as soon as my style-sheet loads** not by requiring each image separately.

My webpack config file is

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    main: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'react-hot!babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
        loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'img'),
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' 
     } // inline base64 URLs for <=10k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

I may be missing some trivial points. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of webpack here ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ahh.... After a long hours of debugging I have finally found the issue. It was my foolishness because of which I struggled. I wanted to delete this question but thought that it would help new comers like me when the stuck to similar issues.

Problem was here

`loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'`

I was setting the limit to file size of **10kb** without really knowing what it does. And the image which I was loading was of size **21kb** ! This happens when you copy some else webpack config files :) **Sign of javascript fatigue !**

Comment: Ah you wanted the images embedded in the css. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Son of a… thank you for NOT deleting this post. And I'm with you, this is completely opaque in the way the docs are written, I assumed everything BELOW 10kb would be dataurl encoded and everything else would pass through…

Answer (score 6):

When using webpack to load your css and the assets they access, your css needs to follow the same module naming rules you use in your JavaScript `import` or `require` calls.

Assuming the `img` folder is in the root of your source tree, you should refer to it like this in scss:

```
// note there is no leading /, which tells "require()" to start from the root of your source tree
$bg-img: url('img/bg.jpg');
```

Or just go completely relative.  Assuming you your source code is like this:

```
/src/styles.scss
/img/bg.jpg
```

Your `styles.scss` could use a relative path:

```
// note the path is relative to where the style.scss is in your source tree.
$bg-img: url('../img/bg.jpg');
```

Comment: I tried both way. Still having same issue.is there any problem with url-loader in web-pack?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but with images with '.jpeg' extension. Change extension to '.jpg' helped me for some reason.